# How to prove that $a^n * b^n = (ab)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you prove that $$a^n * b^n = (ab)^n$$
This is a basic law of exponents used in calculation, but I am unable to prove it.

Comment: How $*$ is defined ?

Comment: It is true iff the operation is commutative. E.g. note that in that case $(ab)^2=abab=aabb=a^2b^2$

Comment: For positives $a$ and $b$ and real $n$ it's not so easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let G be an abelian group. Suppose $a,b \in G$. Then for an arbitrary natural number n, $(ab)^n$ = $(ab)(ab)(ab).......(ab)$ =$(aa.......a)(bb......b)$ =$a^nb^n$

For an integer $n<0$, you will require induction.

However, the issue with your question is that it requires context. Are you working in the real numbers under multiplication? Then it isn’t a group, but the property still holds. If not, and you’re working in a group, then the group needn’t be an abelian group for the property to hold. The property still holds if $a,b$ commute.

Comment: What happens if $n$ is a real number? If you'll see don-voting it's not mine.

Comment: Doesn’t necessarily hold when a,b are complex. More information is required.

Comment: It's exactly, which I say. What happens if $n$ is a real number and $a$ and $b$ are positives? I think in this case there is a very big problem with your reasoning. See please my comment two hours ago.

Comment: If a is real and n is real then it really depends on how you define $a^n$

Comment: I think all these are your work. But a big problem, I think, it's a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: use induction and the commutativity of the multiplication.

Comment: I agree that this is an answer, but I suppose you could have just commented on the original post...

Comment: Thank you, this helped me solve this myself.

Comment: @PratikApshinge you don't get $50$k points by commenting